# Notice: Undefined index: PHP y Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy intentando enviar un formulario, pero al enviarse que la página no recargue, para eso estoy utilizando ajax y después para guardarlos PHP, pero tengo el siguiente problema, me dice
Notice: Undefined index: correo in C:\xampp\htdocs\send\formsubs.php on line 2

CÓDIGO HTML

```html
<form class="form-subs" id="form-sub"  method="post" onsubmit="return subs();">
          <input type="email"  id="correo" name="correo"  placeholder="&#xf0e0; Correo electronico"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="send1" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

CÓDIGO JavaScript

```js
  function subs() {
    var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
    //var fdata = 'correo='+correo;
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'../send/formsubs.php',
      data: 'correo='+correo,
      success:function(msgsub) {
        $("#send1").hide(function() {
          $("#load2").fadeIn(function() {
            $("#load2").delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
              $("#sub-res").html(msgsub);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Y EL CÓDIGO PHP AUN NO ACABADO

```html
<?php
  $correo = $_REQUEST['correo'];
  echo $correo;
 ?>
```

Si alguien me podría ayudar estaría muy agradecido!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo enviar los datos por POST.

```
function subs() {
    var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'../send/formsubs.php',
      data: {correo: correo},
      success:function(msgsub) {
        $("#send1").hide(function() {
          $("#load2").fadeIn(function() {
            $("#load2").delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
              $("#sub-res").html(msgsub);
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

//PHP

```
<?php
  $correo = $_POST['correo'];
  echo $correo;
 ?>
```

Para ver lo que recibes por php escribe `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Hola, al final he conseguido hacerlo, el fallo estaba en que tenia mas de un id con el mismo valor.

Comment: @EugeniBejan Deberías añadir eso como respuesta (explicando dónde ocurría en el código y cómo lo solucionaste) y aceptarla como válida; de ese modo si alguien se encuentra con un problema similar tendrá una referencia